# How to write an XSLT to transform following XML in the following HTML?

Tags: xml, xslt, sparql

```
<result>  
   <binding name="PropertyURI">
      <uri>http://dbpedia.org/ontology/motto</uri>
   </binding> 
   <binding name="Property">
      <literal xml:lang="en">motto</literal>
   </binding>
   <binding name="ValueURI">
      <uri>http://dbpedia.org/ontology/motto</uri>
   </binding>
   <binding name="Value">
      <literal>Ittehad, Tanzim, Yaqeen-e-Muhkam(Urdu)</literal>
   </binding>
</result>
```

I want to transform it like

```
<a href=PropertyURI>Property</a>
<a href=ValueURI>Value</a>
```

Problem is that number of binding tags can different. Sometimes we may have only URIs or ony Values.

How can I know in XSLT that if binding with @name=PropertyURI is available?
If yes then what is the name of next binding @name attribute?

Comment: @stakx Thanks. I looks better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an answer that seems valid but I've just spent 10 minutes testing the following code so :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/result/binding[@name='PropertyURI']"/>
</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="binding">
    <a>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="./uri"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="./following-sibling::binding[1][@name='Property']/literal"/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have tested the one by FrenchKiss. Yes this is fine and I will get a correct link. 
1. what if there wasnt a URI but Just a Literal? In this case what I want Property URI to serve both as href and text in anchor/link. and If there is only Property but no PropertyURI then it will be converted to simple text instead of a link. 
2. What about ValueURI and Value?

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you're looking for, since your description of the problem and your desired output don't seem to be related.  I *think* that what you want to do is find every `binding` element with a `uri` child, find the related `binding` element that has a `literal` child, and use the `uri` and `literal` values to populate an `a` element.

This template assumes that the two `binding` elements are related because the `name` attribute on the one with the `uri` child starts with the `name` attribute on the one with the `literal` child, e.g. "PropertyURI" starts with "Property" and "ValueURI" starts with "Value":

```
<xsl:template match="binding[uri]">
   <xsl:variable name="name" value="@name"/>
   <xsl:variable name="literal" 
                select="/result/binding[starts-with($name, @name)]/literal"/>
   <xsl:if test="$literal">
      <a href="{uri}">
         <xsl:value-of select="$literal"/>
      </a>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

If the related element is simply the *next* `binding` element after the one with the `uri` child, use the above template, replacing the variable assignment with:

```
<xsl:variable name="literal" select="following-sibling::binding[1]/literal"/>
```

Comment: I am getting an error. Attribute value is not allowed on this element
    <xsl:variable name="name" value="@name"/>

Comment: Sorry just some problem with editor. There is no error after I rewrote the  same thing.